# c#, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, non default-folder

Tags: c#, outlook

I need a count, view, edit items of a non-default calendar, but I have a problem to access to it.

How to access to a non-default calendar in c# (for have a Outlook.MAPIFolder) ? please

After create the new "Adhésion" calendar in "\xxx@outlook.fr". I would like to access to it in c# app.

Is it a correct way ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ACC_adhérents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();

            Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("mapi");

            ns.Logon("xxxx@outlook.fr", Missing.Value, true, true);

            Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder parentFolder = inboxFolder.Parent;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder adhesionFolder = parentFolder.Folders["Tâches - Adhésion"];

            Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}, EntryId: {1}", adhesionFolder.Name, adhesionFolder.EntryID);
            Console.WriteLine("Num Items: {0}", adhesionFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

            ns.Logoff();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that folder in a separate store? Or a subfolder of some other folder in your primary store? Or some other place?

Comment: it's a new folder called "Tâches - Adhésion" in "\\xxx@outlook.fr"

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is already opened in Outlook, start with the ns.Folders collection (returns top level folders of all stores in the profile) and drill down to the folder you want. You can also use the Namespace.Stores collection to get to the secondary store you want and then use Store.GetDefaultFolder (for the default folders) or Store.GetRootFolder to strat with the top fodler of the store.